# D3 Simple Line Graph Related Issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

[My line graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HneIj.png)

Making a d3 line graph. Why is there a horizontal line that's appearing on the x axis during the duration of the graph.

Comment: It looks like you have two separate lines on the graph. Please provide your code.

Comment: I'll do it shortly, but it's only one line. I went on dev tools and checked

Comment: what is your last data point x,y values?

Comment: I figured it out. My x-axis is using a ScaleBand and the domain that I was passing to it included duplicate values. I tested it before and after and that seems to be the issue. Anyone have a solution to this?